# How to use FBO's to render two objects

Tags: opengl-es

I've read a lot about FBO's and attaching color buffers, depth buffers, etc.

I understand how to create a texture and a LINE_STRIP by themselves.  But I don't understand how to use FBO's to create a texture and a LINE_STRIP (and multiples of both) on the same screen.

Could someone explain this and possibly provide some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Rendering multiple objects to FBO is done in same way how you render objects to screen. Just forget about FBO for a moment and render your objects like you are rendering to screen.

Comment: I think I know what you mean - just do it sequentially and forget about the buffering aspect, right?   To really nail it down....   If I want to draw a LINE_STRIP followed by a textured object, I'd use a FBO with a color attachment and then use the same FBO with a new color attachment?  OR a second FBO and the new color attachment?  Many thanks.

Comment: If both line and textured object should be rendered on same buffer, then you need one FBO with same attachments. If you need to render them separately - then use two FBOs with different attachments.

Comment: Martins: Could you please provide pseudo code to show the sequence of steps during initialization and rendering to get the line and texture objects to display on the same screen?  The render code will be called repeatedly by the runloop.  It would be greatly appreciated.  Sorry to ask for so much, but I'm having trouble understanding how to put the pieces together.

Comment: I think I get it.  2 key concepts are: (1) use "bind" to set buffer about to work on (as opposed to one time BIND this to that) and (2) depth buffer can be used for more than depth.  Correct?